# How to remove label in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, visualforce

I have added a label in Jquery

```
 $('[id$="refAprtyAppId"]').after('<label class="error" id="refAprtyAppIdError">Error: Referral Id is required.</label>');
```

I have tried

```
$('[id$="refAprtyAppId"]').parent().find("label#refAprtyAppIdError").remove();
```

to remove the label, but it is failed to remove.

Html is

```
 <div class="area">
   <input id="refAprtyAppId" value="" styleClass="externalAppId referralId"/>
 </div>
```

Whats the problem here?

Comment: This code works just fine. Are you sure you have included jQuery?

Comment: Your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/bxddmfj4/. Please check the console for errors.

Comment: Thank you guys. There was an error referencing the jquery library. Thanks again. Now it is solved.

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you use id selector. You have an id there. Use it.

```
 $('#refAprtyAppIdError').remove();
```

Comment: While better logic, there's no reason the OPs original wouldn't be working.

Answer (score 1):

As per the html documentation you are allowed to have multiple id with same name on the same page. If you have multiple "error label" then you can use -

```
$('label.error').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding answer to better clarify my comment.

Your code works fine:

```js
$('[id$="refAprtyAppId"]').after('<label class="error" id="refAprtyAppIdError">Error: Referral Id is required.</label>');

$('#remove').on('click', function() {
  $('[id$="refAprtyAppId"]').parent().find("label#refAprtyAppIdError").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="area">
  <input id="refAprtyAppId" value="" styleClass="externalAppId referralId" />
</div>
<button type='button' id='remove'>Remove Label</button>
```

Check the JavaScript console in your browser for other errors. Its possible that jQuery has not been referenced correctly.